# Hazelcast seems not forming cluster on server

Tags: hazelcast

i try to use hazelcast within my java application (Minecraft-Plugin)! On my computer, all works fine, but on my server the members will not connect to each other. Every member seems to form its own (ego) cluster instead of joining together.

I dont know why and i need help.

Here is my Hazlecast config:

```
Config config = new Config();
    config.setClusterName("core");

    NetworkConfig networkConfig = config.getNetworkConfig();
    networkConfig.setPort(5900);
    
    config.getSerializationConfig().addDataSerializableFactory(1, new UserSerializerFactory());
    MapConfig mapConfig = new MapConfig();
    mapConfig.setName("users");
    mapConfig.setBackupCount(1);
    mapConfig.setTimeToLiveSeconds(30*86400); //30 Tage
    config.addMapConfig(mapConfig);
    hazelcastMember = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    userMap = hazelcastMember.getMap("users");
```

It works fine on my pc but not on my server!

Answer (score 0):

Default configuration uses multicast for discovery, and this is frequently blocked on some hardware types.

Try something like this

```
        Config config = new Config();
  
        TcpIpConfig tcpIpConfig = new TcpIpConfig()
                .setEnabled(true)
                .setMembers(List.of("127.0.0.1:5900"));

        JoinConfig joinConfig = new JoinConfig()
                .setMulticastConfig(new MulticastConfig().setEnabled(false))
                .setTcpIpConfig(tcpIpConfig);

        NetworkConfig networkConfig = new NetworkConfig().setJoin(joinConfig);
        networkConfig.setPort(5900);

        config.setNetworkConfig(networkConfig);
```

ie. Turn off Multicast, use TCP to the list of specified addresses

Comment: Nothing is working with UFW Enabled. UFW seems to block intern connections. Can you help me, find out why?

Comment: If the machines can ping each other, TCP should work. Just list their IP address along the lines of `List.of("12.34.56.78:5900", "12.34.56.79:5900", "12.34.56.80:5900")` and that should work. If it doesn't, can you post the full logs please.